# Concentric sphere and a spherical shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential, gauss-law

I have the following system:

> A non-conducting sphere with radius $R$ is placed inside a spherical non-conducting shell with inner radius $2R$ and outer radius $3R$. The shell and the sphere are Concentric.
>
> It is given that the electric potential inside the sphere is $Ar^2$ for a positive $A$ (and $0\le r\le R$). The shell is charged in a non-uniform charge density $\rho(r)=C \cdot\frac{1}{r}$ for a positive $B$ (and $2R\le r\le 3R$).
>
> I need to find the charge density of the sphere, but I have no idea how.

I can calculate the charge of the shell and thus its electric field, but I don't know if it helps me to figure out the charge density of the sphere.

Comment: Hint: What is the electric field inside a charged spherical shell?

Comment: @AfterShave I don't know, since both the sphere and the shell are non-conducting (if the shell was conducting, the field would be zero, but this is not the case)

Comment: The field inside a non-conducting shell is also zero, so it is not important for your purpose.

Comment: @AfterShave Why? If it is true, using Gauss's law I am getting that the charge density of the sphere is zero.

Comment: What I meant was, the contribution to the electric field from the shell is zero on the inside. In other words only the contribution from the sphere matters here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the electric field is the negative gradient of the electric potential, you could easily calculate the field. From there, calculating the charge density is straightforward using Gauss' Law or Maxwell I. For any Gaussian sphere of radius $r<R$ concentric with the system,
$$\rho(r)=\epsilon\left(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E(r)}\right),\,0\leq r \leq R. $$

Or, you could realize that the divergence of the gradient of a scalar potential is the Laplacian of said potential and derive the charge density directly:

$$\rho(r) = -\epsilon\ \nabla^2 \ U(r), \, 0 \leq r\leq R.$$

The outer shell is irrelevant.

Comment: The OP actually mentioned a non-conducting shell but the conclusion remains the same.

Comment: @AfterShave Thanks. Edited.